# Issue with Objective C Files in Swift Unit Test

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, unit-testing

I am running into a problem here trying to run my unit test.
I have a swift project but there are some Objective C files.
The project builds fine normally, however, when I try to run the unit test, it gives me build error saying "Use of unresolved identifier"

I am currently pulling all my hair out try to resolve this problem, any help is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can add MBProgressHUD with CocoaPods, not manually? It will help you resolve all the problems with external frameworks.

Comment: Also including `.h` file in compile sources can cause build errors about duplicating symbols... Try to remove it